# Possible EF6 beta 1 Migration bug. Codefirst migration deadlock

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

My EF database is deleted, and I have some changes in my model. I want to recreate my database. But ef gives me some weird messages. It said I first should write pending model changes to Code-First migration because it can't update database to match current model. But when I tried to write that pending model changes to Code-First migration, it said that I should apply pending migrations to database.

[image]

I also tried `-Sript` option to `Update-Database` but it gives me same result.

[image]

What should I do? Revert my pending changes to my model?

Comment: have you tried enabling automatic migration?

Comment: I tried, and it worked. But my company state that all migrations should be code-based. They doesn't allow automatic migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly specifying the migrations with Update-Database one at a time. If that doesn't work, try applying the InitialCreate by itself, then re-creating/Adding the ChangePegawaiToTPT. Be sure to have a backup copy first...

There are some cases where many-to-many relationships are being named differently in rc1 than in the beta, which causes some headaches.